# VisualStudio intellisense and Lambdas. How can I make it not select an actual type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, lambda, intellisense

I'm working on a utility class and one of my methods is defined:

```
void SomeMethod(Action<T> a);
```

The awkward thing is that in Visual Studio 2010, when you start typing:

```
someClass.SomeMethod(x ...
```

when you press the [x] key, then [space], the intellisense automatically selects whatever the first class was that started with "X", typically some "XmlWhatever" class

However, if I change my method signature to:

```
void SomeMethod(Expression<Action<T>> a);
```

Then if I start typing the same usage, pressing [x][space] puts the actual letter 'x'. It seems the intellisense handles putting in a lambda were a parameter of type `Expression<>` is expected, but not of type `Action<>`.

Is there some way to make the VS intellisense handle the first case properly? I can't actually pass in an Expression because my intended usage is:

```
someClass.SomeMethod(x => x.Property1 = 123);
```

which leads to the error CS0832: An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator
Hence I do want the `Action<>` to be passed in, I don't really need an Expression, it just fixes the intellisense.

It is really annoying as it is, because as I type in the Action parameters, I end up having to press [x][esc][space][=][>] to get the text "x =>", adding the "escape" keypress to close the intellisense popup. Any thoughts or ideas?

---

***Edit:***

OK I actually have to re-phrase my question a bit.  My sample code above wasn't exactly accurate. It seems that this is the case with VS intellisense:

This IS handled correctly:

```
public static T SomeMethod<T>(Action<T> actions) where T : class
```

but this is NOT handled correctly by intellisense:

```
public static T IsT4<T>(params Action<T>[] actions) where T : class
```

So it seems intellisense doesn't like the `params`.

Comment: That's exactly what I do and I would also like to know the answer but I hope you're kidding about modifying code to make IntelliSense work properly.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me - but then I've got Resharper.  Give it a try.

Comment: @Phil ReSharper replaces the VS intelisense box with its own which behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explicit array creation syntax to work around this problem:

```
obj.IsT4(new Action<SomeType>[] { x => ...
```

You can also create an additional overload of the `IsT4` method which takes exactly 1 action delegate.

Answer (score -1):

Tools | Options | C# | Intellisense

Uncheck 'Committed by pressing the space bar'.

[image]